# How to create read transform using ParDo and DoFn in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

According to the [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/#when-to-implement-using-the-source-ap) the recommended way 
to write simple sources is by using Read Transforms and `ParDo`. Unfortunately the Apache Beam docs has let me down here.

I'm trying to write a simple unbounded data source which emits events using a `ParDo` but the compiler keeps complaining about the input type of the `DoFn` object:

```
message: 'The method apply(PTransform<? super PBegin,OutputT>) in the type PBegin is not applicable for the arguments (ParDo.SingleOutput<PBegin,Event>)'
```

My attempt:

```
public class TestIO extends PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<Event>> {

    @Override
    public PCollection<Event> expand(PBegin input) {
        return input.apply(ParDo.of(new ReadFn()));
    }

    private static class ReadFn extends DoFn<PBegin, Event> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void process(@TimerId("poll") Timer pollTimer) {
            Event testEvent = new Event(...);

            //custom logic, this can happen infinitely
            for(...) {
                context.output(testEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell more about the kind of source you're trying to write? It's possible that there is a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: @jkff Eventually I want to poll all new records every 5 seconds from an SQL database and output them as protobuf objects. I don't think that's possible with an existing Beam source?

Comment: OK if you want to look for new records in the results of a query, you should probably use the Watch transform https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Watch.java  - please take a look and see if it looks like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A `DoFn` performs element-wise processing. As written, `ParDo.of(new ReadFn())` will have type `PTransform<PCollection<PBegin>, PCollection<Event>>`. Specifically, the `ReadFn` indicates it takes an *element* of type `PBegin` and returns 0 or more elements of type `Event`.

Instead, you should use an actual `Read` operation. There are [a variety provided](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/). You can also use `Create` if you have a specific set of in-memory collections to use.

If you need to create a custom source you should use the [Read transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Read.html). Since you're using timers, you likely want to create an Unbounded Source (a stream of elements).

Comment: I'd like to clarify that this guidance applies only when you can not implement your source using ParDo's. The Source API is very cumbersome to program against and you should avoid it if it's at all possible to express your IO without it. The missing bit in your ParDo solution is a collection to pass to the ParDo: usually it's something like Create.of(seed element), e.g. to read files, Create.of(filepattern) + ParDo(split filepattern into files) + fusion break + ParDo(read each file).

Comment: Ben is right that if you're implementing a streaming IO, then you might UnboundedSource; however you might not. If it's a simple matter of polling, then you might get what you want by combining a GenerateSequence transform as a periodic "tick generator" (use the methods that allow you to control the rate of data production) with a ParDo that, on each tick, polls for some more data.