# Apply not applicable with ParDo and DoFn using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am implementing a Pub/Sub to BigQuery pipeline. It looks similar to [How to create read transform using ParDo and DoFn in Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470088/how-to-create-read-transform-using-pardo-and-dofn-in-apache-beam), but here, I have already a PCollection created.

I am following what is described in the [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms) to implement a ParDo operation to prepare a table row using the following pipeline:

```
static class convertToTableRowFn extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, TableRow> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        PubsubMessage message = c.element();
        // Retrieve data from message
        String rawData = message.getData();
        Instant timestamp = new Instant(new Date());
        // Prepare TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow().set("message", rawData).set("ts_reception", timestamp);
        c.output(row);
    }
}

// Read input from Pub/Sub
pipeline.apply("Read from Pub/Sub",PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromTopic(topicPath))
        .apply("Prepare raw data for insertion", ParDo.of(new convertToTableRowFn()))
        .apply("Insert in Big Query", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(BQTable));
```

I found the DoFn function in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/maciekrb/9c73cb94a258e177e023dba9049dda13).

I keep getting the following error:

```
The method apply(String, PTransform<? super PCollection<PubsubMessage>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<PubsubMessage> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ParDo.SingleOutput<PubsubMessage,TableRow>)
```

I always understood that a ParDo/DoFn operations is a element-wise PTransform operation, am I wrong ? I never got this type of error in Python, so I'm a bit confused about why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, `ParDos` are element-wise transforms and your approach looks correct.

What you're seeing is the compilation error. Something like this happens when the argument type of the `apply()` method that was inferred by java compiler doesn't match the type of the actual input, e.g. `convertToTableRowFn`.

From the error you're seeing it looks like java infers that the second parameter for `apply()` is of type `PTransform<? super PCollection<PubsubMessage>,OutputT>`, while you're passing the subclass of `ParDo.SingleOutput<PubsubMessage,TableRow>` instead (your `convertToTableRowFn`). Looking at the definition of [`SingleOutput`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/06128f27d1780f25c23ca65cc7ace693a78dac80/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.java#L576-L577) your `convertToTableRowFn` is basically a `PTransform<PCollection<? extends PubsubMessage>, PCollection<TableRow>>`. And java fails to use it in `apply` where it expects `PTransform<? super PCollection<PubsubMessage>,OutputT>`.

What looks suspicious is that java didn't infer the `OutputT` to `PCollection<TableRow>`. One reason it would fail to do so if you have other errors. Are you sure you don't have other errors as well?

For example, looking at `convertToTableRowFn` you're calling `message.getData()` which doesn't exist when I'm trying to do it and it fails compilation there. In my case I need to do something like this instead: `rawData = new String(message.getPayload(), Charset.defaultCharset())`. Also `.to(BQTable))` expects a string (e.g. a string representing the BQ table name) as an argument, and you're passing some unknown symbol `BQTable` (maybe it exists in your program somewhere though and this is not a problem in your case).

After I fix these two errors your code compiles for me, `apply()` is fully inferred and the types are compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your input ! It helped me ! I didn't write the import part and this is where one of the problem was coming from. I was using `import com.google.api.services.pubsub.model.PubsubMessage;` instead of `import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;`, so I wasn't accessing the good method. And for the BQTable, I forgot to add it to my code but it was here :-)